# Nginx - rodando app php e node no mesmo domínio com portas diferentes

Tags: php, node.js, servidor, nginx

estou configurando um blocks no nginx, mas estou com dificuldade para rodar duas apps distintas, veja a seguinte situação:

- Tenho 2 apps (PHP e Node.js)
- apenas um dominio (exemplo.com.br) e preciso apontar a porta 80 para a aplicação PHP e a 8080 para a app node.js.
- Já fiz o apontamento da app PHP e está ok, porém não consigo acessar a app node na 8080

Veja o meu arquivo de block para php

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name exemplo.br;

    # root directive should be global
    root   /var/www/app-php/public;
    index  index.php;

    access_log /var/www/app-php/log/access.log;
    error_log  /var/www/app-php/log/error.log;

    client_max_body_size 1024M;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
   }

   location  ~ /\.ht{
       deny all;
   }

}
```

E o block do node.js

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            # proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            # proxy_pass http://IP-PRIVADO-SERVER:3000;
            # proxy_pass http://exemplo.com.br:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host:8080;
            # proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode estar errado, por favor?

Obs.: no servidor que estou configurando o `nginx` não tem `iptables` instalado e já testei a aplicação `node.js` na porta `80` e funcionou normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui encontrar a solução, foram dois problemas que estavam interrompendo a execução desse direcionamento.

**1.** 8080 é um alias da porta 80, então não seria possível fazer isso para o mesmo domínio. Solução troquei para a porta 81

**2.** o servidor que eu estava configurando tem um firewall externo, por isso bloqueava outras portas dinamicas que só funcionavam internamente usando curl -s dominio.com.br:3000

Comment: Kaio, vc poderia me mandar seu contato?